# perl code taking values from three files and printing in another file

Tags: perl

I have one file named `1.txt` having values like:

```
a
b
c
...
```

Second file named `2.txt` like this:

```
a 123,
a 156,
a 899,
c 255,
```

Third file named `3.txt` like this:

```
a 236,
a 890,
b 123,
```

How can read the values from all three files above and write my results in a single file like the one below:

```
a  123  236,
-  156  890,
-  899  -,
b  -   123,
```

The files have not equal lines and none of lines are about 10000. I have to use Perl for this.

I have to take the values from the first file.
I have to take the second file and I have to take the values of the second column of the second file corresponding to values of first file.

Similarly I have to take values from the third file.

And I have to write my results in an output file like
values from first file in first column, all the corresponding values from the second file in the second column of output-file and all the corresponding values from the third file in the third column of output-file.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I do not see why you need the first file. Are the second and third file sorted by the first column?

Comment: Question is not clear. Post the code that you have tried

Comment: @choroba sorry, i had to tell, second and third files have random values they are not sorted that's why i need first file..

Comment: Don't be afraid to post your effort and use the 'homework' tag if this is an assignment.

Comment: Another missing detail: is it possible to have `x 1 2` in file 2 or 3 without `x` appearing in file 1? If so, what the output should be in such a case?

Comment: no, for each value in file one there may be a value either in file 2 or in file 3, it may be that corresponding to any value in first file there may be no value exist in file2 or file3. but for values which are written in file 2 and file 3 there exist a value in file 1

Comment: This appears to be a FAQ, same question from may at http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=903477 and http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=903867

Comment: Are these always sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Read the three files: the first can be read into a simple array, the other two into hashes where the hash value is an array (reference to an array).

Read through the first array in sorted order.

For each value in the first array, find the array from the second and third files (the corresponding hashes), sorting the array values into order.  Handle the printing appropriately, dealing with missing values in the second and third columns and repeated values in the first column specially.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by reading the contents of `2.txt` and storing it in a hash of arrayrefs. For example, if `2.txt` is this:

```
a 123,
a 156,
a 899,
c 255,
```

then the data structure would be this:

```
{ a => [123, 156, 899],
  c => [255]
}
```

Then, do the same for `3.txt`.

Only then does it make sense to read through `1.txt`. For each line of `1.txt`, you would look up the appropriate arrays from the above data structures, and iterate over those arrays (using something like `for(my $i = 0; $i < @two && $i < @three; ++$i)`), printing your results.

Comment: thanks,i understand little but i couldn't understand fully can u please explain in detail.